# Interacting with audio from entire device with a PWA

Tags: javascript, audio, progressive-web-apps

I am making a PWA and I wanted to interact with audio from sources other than my PWA for visualization and equalization of the sound, I was wondering if anyone knew any leads for how to interact with the system audio?

Comment: a browser can't interact with system audio - unless you mean you want to get input from the microphone and output to the speakers

Comment: @JaromandaX Would it be possible on chromeOS as that relies on PWA?

Comment: good question. If only the makers of chromeOS had some sort of "search" mechanism whereby you would enter a phrase like "chromeOS pwa audio" and a list of sites were returned that were relevant to this so called "search" :D [like this](https://chromeos.dev/en/web/powerful-pwas#media-streaming-encoding-decoding)

Comment: @JaromandaX I may have misread the 4 option but I did not see what could allow interaction with audio on the system not created by my PWA.

Comment: Oh, I didn't really read that